# What legendaries can be found shiny by soft-reset?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-sixth-generation, pokemon-fifth-generation

What legendary Pokemon can be soft reset to farm for a shiny variant, and, in which games?

Example: If Groudon in Ruby can but cannot in Omega Ruby, make sure to tell.

One more thing, I do not care about the Game Boy Pokemon games legendaries, just because I can not get them to my newer games. You do not need to include any of them in your answer. I do care about Game Boy Advanced though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/games/shiny.shtml), starting in Pokémon Black & White, the developers started instituting locks where Pokémon could be caught in a wild but prevented from being shiny. These locks are mostly done **on the signature legendary Pokémon of the games**, but do range further.

These Pokemon are:

- *Victini*, *Reshiram* and *Zekrom* in BW
- *Reshiram* and *Zekrom* in B2W2
- *Articuno*, *Zapdos*, *Moltres*, *Mewtwo*, *Xerneas*, *Yveltal* and *Zygarde* in XY
- *Kyogre*, *Groudon*, *Rayquaza* and *Deoxys* in ORAS

Comment: So I can still mainly get the secondary legendaries Shiny in the newer games?

Comment: Yes, many shiny hunters have uploaded videos on YouTube, so I'm pretty sure you can get every legendary in its shiny form, but those 4 I've listed.

Comment: I believe Kyurem is also shiny locked in B2W2, but not in BW. Also, all Wondercard Pokemon are shiny locked, which means all event Pokemon that aren't received in game through a Wondercard-unlocked event can't be shiny. This currently includes Celebi, Arceus, Keldeo, Meloetta and Diancie (as well as the Pokeball and Fancy patterns of Vivillon). These 5(7) and Victini, Xerneas, Yveltal and Zygarde are the only Pokemon not available in their shiny form since ORAS brought back Reshiram and Zekrom as non-shiny locked.

Comment: @scenia I don't know about Kyurem, I have a shiny one and I don't know from which game is. Of course wondercard pokemon are shiny-locked, you can obtain their shiny version only if they are released shiny (like recently Jirachi).

Comment: Well, "of course" might not be the correct term, I can totally see why someone would neither know nor expect this. Especially since those that come in in-game events that are unlocked via Wondercards *can* be shiny (e.g. Mew, Shaymin and Darkrai in some regions). Manaphy also is a notable exception.

Comment: Anyway in the link I provided there's the list of event and unobtainable shiny-locked legendaries: Celebi, Arceus, Victini, Keldeo, Meloetta, Xerneas, Yveltal, Zygarde and Diancie.